# Pygames not working

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I bought a new computer and tried putting on pygame when i try to run this code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1176,674),0,32)
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathaneuteneier/Documents/how", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically

```
     import error
```

This meas that the interpreter is unable to correctly "import" the module into your program.
Also , in the interactive mode, if you type

```
    import pygame
```

then what is the result?
In any case, Try downloading the pygame module again  from the web.
http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
Also, the error can be due to the imcompatibility of the 32 bit and the 64 bit version. Download the correct version from the link provided above. To check which (32 or 64) bit you are using. Type this in the interactive mode:-

```
    import platform
    platform.architecture()
```

This will give you the correct bit order of python interpreter you are running